# how to compare values retrieved from two different fetch array

Tags: php

I have two fetch arrays retrieved from the database, and try to compare two values until they have the matching, but it seems bit hard to figure out where I got wrong.

the two database have upto 2 jobrequestnumber so, the number of the matching is supposedly two, but it only counts one(indicated below).

```
 $value1=array();
 $value2 =array();

 $queryfordispatch = "select jobrequestnumber from dispatch";
 $resultfordispatch = mysql_query($queryfordispatch);
 $valuefordispatch =mysql_fetch_array($resultfordispatch);
 $value1 = $valuefordispatch['jobrequestnumber'];

 $queryforjobrequest = "select jobrequestnumber from jobrequest";
 $resultforjobrequest = mysql_query($queryfordispatch);
 $valueforjobrequest =mysql_fetch_array($resultforjobrequest);
 $value2 = $valueforjobrequest['jobrequestnumber'];

 $cfd=count($valuefordispatch);
 $cfj=count($valueforjobrequest);
```

//In this for loop, if I try to echo the value of $value1, it only produce the value of "1"

```
for($i=1; $i<=$cfd; $i++){
for($j=1; $j<=$cfj; $j++){
if ($value1 == $value2 ){

    $queryforupdate ="UPDATE jobrequest SET status = 'processed' where jobrequestnumber = $value2 ";
    mysql_query($queryforupdate);
  }
 }
}
```

So the result that I expect is that

jobnum

```
 1=1? yes --> update
 1=2? no  --> discard
 2=1? no  --> discard
 2=2? yes --> update
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Put values of `$valuefordispatch` and `$valueforjobrequest` here and tell us what should be the result.

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO instead of mysql_ functions, they've been deprecated.

Comment: Where do $value1 and $value2 get set to different values, at the moment although you iterate the count of the two returned arrays, the values never change.

Comment: so can I ask how I get different values?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

If you 're trying to see if array1 and array2 share values then use something like this.

```
$a = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$b = array('A','B','C','4','5','6','7','E','F');
$num_shared = 0;

foreach($a as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($val, $b)) {
        echo $val . '<br />';
        $num_shared++;
    }
}

echo '<strong>'. $num_shared . '</strong>';
```

Comment: It will prompt with number of the same values I guess, but I want to select a index where it has the same value, or retrieve the same one. In addition, I should use fetch_array

Comment: Use an associative array and when you use array_intersect or in_array, just check for the index of that associative item

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

As for finding the **difference** between two arrays, one can always use **[`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)**:

> ```
> <?php
> //Example #1 array_diff() example
> $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
> $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
> $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
>
> print_r($result);
> ?>
> ```
>
> Multiple occurrences in $array1 are all treated the same way. This
>   will output:
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [1] => blue
> )
> ```

However, to compare each value separately, you need to loop through both arrays at the same time (with a `for` loop, preferably), and compare each and every item. Which is kind of what you're already doing.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will help a lot for the future, but is there any way that I can retrieve the same values from the array ?

Comment: @Giantrain: That can only be done with a loop (which is kind of what you're doing already). This will give you the items which are found in `$array1` which aren't in `$array2`.

Comment: Sorry, the same values from the two array*, so items are found in $array1 which are also in $array2. This is the expected result ;)